# Requests to local CouchDB have 40ms latency

Tags: performance, linux, couchdb

Requests to a CouchDB instance on the same machine have about 40ms latency when HTTP keepalive is used by the client, about 0-1ms latency when the client does not use keepalive. What causes this latency?

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm). CouchDB sends the HTTP headers and the response body in separate calls, causing the kernel to not deliver the response body for 40ms.

As a workaround, you can use [this LD_PRELOAD shim](http://git.thejh.net/?p=netboost.git) to completely turn off Nagle's algorithm for the database process.